# macOS: Prevent JxBrowser (Java) Chromium subprocess from showing Dock icons

Tags: java, macos, jxbrowser

We just updated to JxBrowser 6.13 and now, when we launch our (.app bundled) application on macOS, we get 3 icons in the dock. Our regular app icon, and two new (forever bouncing) icons representing the chromium subprocesses necessary for running (I assume.)

I know how to prevent my (parent) app from showing its doc icon by modifying my Info.plist file, but I can't prevent the subprocess icons from showing up too, without preventing all 3.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to not be reproducible in the current version of JxBrowser (6.18 at the moment). You can get it by the following link: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/discussions/topics/9000039314